# Cordova: Android keyboard hides when switching fields

Tags: android, forms, cordova, input, keyboard

When switching text inputs in my Cordova Android, app the keyboard hides, and the user is forced to tap the input *again* to focus it.

Oddly, **this only happens when text is typed into an input**. If both are left blank, the user can switch focus without the keyboard hiding.

This happens with two fields as simple as this:

`<input type="text" placeholder="input1"> <input type="text" placeholder="input2">`

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding of Meteor, we can achieve the auto focus function by adding the following lines in **mobile-config.js**:

```
App.info({...});
App.setPreference('KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction', false);
```

But I have found a blog post which may be helpful to you: http://blog.sanuker.com/?p=457